# Special characters in Python Flask's reqparse.RequestParser()

Tags: python, python-unicode, flask-restful

When adding the argument as follows

```
    self.request_parser.add_argument(
        name='address',
        required=True,
        type=str,
        help="Needs argument: 'address' - The address"
    )
```

where self.request_parser is an instance of `reqparse.RequestParser()` it works pefectly fine if my request is `{'address': 'Gyvelvej'}`, but as soon as I add the special character *æ* as in `{'address': 'Torpevænget'}` the applications throws an **400 BAD REQUEST**, stating that `address` is missing.

In that case, when printing `request.data` yields `{"address":"Torpevænget"}`, so it is present, but apparently not available for reqparse.

Is there any way to make this work?

I'm sending the requests via AngularJS resource, and I would prefer not to alter that code, since I expect this application collaborate with multiple different clients.

**EDIT:** Answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer my self, after I tagged the question with python-unicode

Changing type to `unicode` fixes the problem, i.e.

```
self.request_parser.add_argument(
    name='address',
    required=True,
    type=unicode,
    help="Needs argument: 'address' - The address"
)
```